# How do I develop a maven plugin using Groovy in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, groovy, maven-plugin

I want to write a Maven plugin in Groovy, but under Eclipse (Galileo).

- I've downloaded and installed Groovy-Eclipse plugin
- I've created my very simple POM file (included below).
- I've created a simple Echo mojo and place it under  "/src/main/groovy/com/acme/maven/plugins/foo".
- I performed "Import Existing Maven Project" in Eclipse (using M2Eclipse plugin).

The problem is that I don't see "src/main/groovy" as a source folder, which makes it hard to develop: 
- I have to create the package directory structure (com/acme/maven/plugins/foo) manually
- Refactoring probably won't work easily
- Incremental probably won't work.

How do you guys develop your Maven plugins using Groovy in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitvly install the Groovy-Eclipse plugin if you plan to develop Groovy code in Eclipse. You can find all the details here:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin

You should also add the Groovy Maven Plugin to your `pom.xml` like this (see [this page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Building+Groovy+Projects) for details):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Now update your Eclipse project configuration via `Right-click on project -> Maven -> Update project configuration`. Now you should see that the `src/main/groovy` folder has been added to the source folders.

Comment: I have installed Groovy-Eclipse plugin (I'll update my question)

Comment: You should also add the groovy maven plugin. I updated my answer!

Comment: Well, my main mistake was working with 1.0-rc5 version of both gmaven-plugin and gmaven-mojo.

Comment: Oh, and I had to add the following element to my POM: <properties>
  <gmaven.runtime>1.5</gmaven.runtime> <!-- read by gmaven -->
 </properties>

Answer (score 0):

Use [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Implementing+Maven+Plugins) and the eclipse plugin as [suggested by chkal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113210/how-do-i-develop-a-maven-plugin-using-groovy-in-eclipse/4113359#4113359).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to GMaven, and Groovy-Eclipse, there is m2eclipse support for Groovy-Eclipse that should be installed separately.  Go to the Groovy-Eclipse snapshot update site:

http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.6/

And install the feature from there.  This feature will ensure that your groovy/maven projects are set up correctly when they are imported.

Comment: From some odd reason, even without this integration it works, after I've set the plugin version to 1.0 (and not 1.0-rc5). I'll wait for them to release it properly and not use bleeding egde releases. BTW: Where do they mention this integration at their site? I couldn't find it.

Comment: The Groovy-Eclipse integration for m2eclipse is not bleeding edge.  It is working for all basic cases.  We just haven't heard enough community feedback to promote it to being a general release.